# How to grab internal text from matching lines in multiline text in python?

Tags: python

I have text file called `test.txt`. From `test.txt`, I want to grab the lines that start with `>lcl` then to extract values after `locus` tag and within close bracket`]`. I want to do the same thing for values after `location`. The result I want is shown below. How can I do this in python?

**desired result**

```
SS1G_08319  <504653..>506706
SS1G_12233  complement(<502136..>503461)
SS1G_02099  <2692251..>2693298
SS1G_05227  complement(<1032740..>1033620)
```

**test.txt**

```
>lcl|NW_001820825.1_gene_208 [locus_tag=SS1G_08319] [db_xref=GeneID:5486863] [partial=5',3'] [location=<504653..>506706] [gbkey=Gene]
ATGGGCAAAGCTTCTAGGAATAAGACGAAGCATCGCGCTGATCCTACCGCAAAAACTGTTAAGCCACCCA
CTGACCCAGAGCTTGCAGCAATTCGAGTTAACAAAATTCTGCCAATTCTCCAAGATTTACAAAGTGCAGA
CCAGTCAAAGAGATCAACTGCTGCAACTGCCATTGCGAACCTCGTTGACGATACAAAATGTCGAAAGTTA
TTCTTGAGAGAGCAAATTGTTCGTATTCTACTCGAACAAACCCTTACAGACTCAAGCATGGAAACTAGAA
>lcl|NW_001820817.1_gene_205 [locus_tag=SS1G_12233] [db_xref=GeneID:5483157] [partial=5',3'] [location=complement(<502136..>503461)] [gbkey=Gene]
ATGATCTGTAATACGCTCGGTGTTCCACCCTGCAACAGAATTCTTAAGAAATTCTCCGTTGGCGAGAGTC
GTCTCGAAATTCAAGACTCAGTACGAGGCAAAGATGTCTACATCATTCAATCGGGTGGAGGAAAGGCCAA
TGATCACTTCGTGGATCTTTGCATTATGATCTCCGCATGCAAAACTGGCTCTGCCAAGCGCGTCACTGTC
GTCCTTCCTTTGTTTCCTTATTCACGACAACCTGATCTGCCATACAACAAGATTGGCGCACCACTTGCCA
>lcl|NW_001820834.1_gene_1034 [locus_tag=SS1G_02099] [db_xref=GeneID:5493612] [partial=5',3'] [location=<2692251..>2693298] [gbkey=Gene]
ATGGCTTCTGTTTACAAGTCATTATCAAAGACCTCTGGTCATAAAGAAGAAACCCCGACTGGTGTCAAGA
AAAACAAGCAAAGAGTTTTGATCTTGTCTTCAAGAGGAATAACTTACAGGTATATAAATTTGTACCGATG
CGATGCAAAAAATCGCAGGAAAATGCTAACTCTACAACTTAGACATCGACATCTCCTCAATGACCTTGCG
TCCCTACTTCCCCACGGTAGGAAAGATGCGAAACTCGATACCAAGTCAAAGCTTTATCAATTGAATGAAT
>lcl|NW_001820830.1_gene_400 [locus_tag=SS1G_05227] [db_xref=GeneID:5489764] [partial=5',3'] [location=complement(<1032740..>1033620)] [gbkey=Gene]
ATGGCGGACGGATGTAAGTTAATTGATGTTCCTACTATTCCAGACTAATATTTGTTCTCGTCCCTACAAT
GCATTCGGAACGGATGGTACTCAGTTAACTTTGTAACTAATACAACGTCTAGTAAATGACCAAAGAACTG
```

I am new in python so I tried to come up with something like this:

```
results = []
f = open("test.txt", 'r')

while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    file_name = line.split("locus_tag")[-1].strip()
    f.readline()  # skip line 
    data_seq1 = f.readline().strip()
    f.readline()  
    data_seq2 = f.readline().strip()
    results.append((file_name, data_seq1))
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What have you tried?

Comment: @LieRyan Please see my edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, the most trival way to solve your issue is by using `regex` like this example:

```
import re

results = []
# Open the file in the 'read' mode
# with statement will take care to close the file
with open('YOUR_FILE_PATH', 'r') as f_file:
    # Read the entire file as a one string
    data = f_file.read()
    # Here we search for the string that begins with '>lcl'
    # and in which we find the [locus_tag=...] and [localtion=...]
    results = re.findall(r'>lcl.*\[locus_tag=(.*?)\].*\[location=(.*?)\]', data)

for locus, location in results:
    print(locus, location)
```

Output:

```
SS1G_08319 <504653..>506706
SS1G_12233 complement(<502136..>503461)
SS1G_02099 <2692251..>2693298
SS1G_05227 complement(<1032740..>1033620)
```

Another variation using a `dict` as a result and by splitting lines:

```
import re

results = {}
with open('fichier1', 'r') as f_file:
    # Here we split the file's lines into a list
    data = f_file.readlines()
    for line in data:
        # Here we search for the lines that begins by '>lcl'
        # and same as the first attempt
        results.update(re.findall(r'^>lcl.*\[locus_tag=(.*?)\].*\[location=(.*?)\]', line))

for locus, location in results.items():
    print(locus, location)
```

Edit: Creating a `DataFrame` and exporting it into a `csv` file:

```
import re
from pandas import DataFrame as df

results = {}
with open('fichier1', 'r') as f_file:
    data = f_file.readlines()
    for line in data:
        results.update(re.findall(
            r'^>lcl.*\[locus_tag=(.*?)\].*\[location=(.*?)\]',
            line
        ))

df_ = df(
    list(results.items()),
    index=range(1, len(results) + 1),
    columns=['locus', 'location']
)
print(df_)
df_.to_csv('results.csv', sep=',')
```

It will prints and creates a file called `results.csv`:

```
        locus                        location
1  SS1G_12233    complement(<502136..>503461)
2  SS1G_08319                <504653..>506706
3  SS1G_05227  complement(<1032740..>1033620)
4  SS1G_02099              <2692251..>2693298
```

Comment: Can't argue with those results.

Comment: @MAPK. Python has a really good regex tutorial as part of the official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html. You will find that this answer I'd quite simple after reading through it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for your comment. Can you explain me why you don't argue with the results ?

Comment: @ChihebNexus One more thing- how do you append the results to create a dataframe and write as a csv file?

Comment: @Chiheb. My comment was made to express general support. "Can't argue with ..." is a fairly common expression meaning that "..." is so good that it speaks for itself. I did not mean that I had any plan to argue with your results :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist I see. English is my third language i didn't get it at first sight <shame on me >. Thanks again for your comments.

Comment: No shame whatsoever, I assure you. You're doing great as it is, and I'm happy to have introduced you to a new expression. I am guessing that French and Python ate the first two languages :)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to present two alternative solutions. One that will extract any set of named tags on your line using regular expressions, and another which is a complete travesty but shows a way to do it without regular expressions.

**Generic Regex Solution**

```
import re

def get_tags(filename, tags, prefix='>lcl'):
    tags = set(tags)
    pattern = re.compile(r'\[(.+?)=(.+?)\]')

    def parse_line(line):
        return {m.group(1): m.group(2) for m in pattern.finditer(line) if m.group(1) in tags}

    with open(filename) as f:
        return [parse_line(line) for line in f if prefix is None or line.startswith(prefix)]
```

This function returns a list of dictionaries keyed by the tags you are interested in you would use it like this:

```
tags = ['locus_tag', 'location']
result = get_tags('test.txt', tags)
```

You could use the result to get the exact printout you want:

```
for line in get_tags('test.txt', tags):
    print(*(line[tag] for tag in tags))
```

This has the advantage that you can use the results as you chose later, and configure which tags you extract.

**No Regex Solution**

This version is just something I wrote to show that is possible. Please do not emulate it, as the code is a pointless maintenance burden.

```
def get_tags2(filename, tags, prefix='>lcl'):
    tags = set(tags)

    def parse_line(line):
        items = [tag.split(']')[0].split('=') for tag in line.split('[')[1:]]
        return dict(tag for tag in items if tag[0] in tags)

    with open(filename) as f:
        return [parse_line(line) for line in data if prefix is None or line.startswith(prefix)]
```

This function behaves just like the first one but the parsing function is a hot mess by comparison. It's also much less robust, e.g. because it's assumed that all your square brackets are more or less matching.

Here is an IDEOne link showing off both methods: https://ideone.com/X2LKqL